# Version 2.8 or 2.79 to start learning Blender?

Tags: versions

I`ve been using Cinema 4D for many years and now I´m thinking in migrating to Blender. My question is, which version would be better to start learning? I mean, Blender changed a lot in version 2.8 but it´s still in beta.

Comment: you could learn 2.79 and feel home with blender 2.80 IMO. a few shortcuts are different, some GUI changes here and there and the new engine but overall the workflow is the same. you wouldn't need to re-learn nothing major.. just getting use to. having said that if you don't need it professionally but just for learning/personal, I would go for 2.8 as is the future of blender and overall (despite the alpha/beta stage) a better and more user friendly experience IMHO. I guess a big No for 2.8 would be if you plan on relying on external addons. most of them are not ready yet

Comment: I would start with 2.79, since it will be around for a lot of time, most tutorials and addons refer to that version, I saw a question of a user looking for an old alpha 2.8 to be able to follow a tutorial O_o. When 2.8 will stabilize, at least in beta, you'll already have a good grip of blender workflow, and the switch/comparison will be less hard. That said, this question will get opinion based answers like mine, thus not a good question here :)

Comment: Related [Learn Blender 2.7 now or wait for the 2.8 Beta release? (closed)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122408/learn-blender-2-7-now-or-wait-for-the-2-8-beta-release)

Comment: I wouldn't close that one actually. Opinion based or not, it's a question for a lot of people that deserves some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might seem like a waste of time when 2.8 is supposed to come out in early 2019.

Yet...

Both versions are not entirely different, many aspects and concepts will remain the same and there's one major benefit to 2.79:

There's abundant information on it available right now. Look at SE here. Most answers use pre 2.8 as their foundation.

And it's not too helpful to wonder whether something was your fault or a bug.

So I claim that it's easier to get roughly familiar with 2.79 and then 2.8

It's also a good thing to be able to compare the differences. I started with 2.12 and I had to deal with the 2.3 and 2.5 revolution. Not counting the animation overhaul in 2.2x. Now I'll add the 2.8 revolution. Can't shake me anymore. it's 0.1 versions late anyway!!

And as crazy as it sounds: limitations aside, I feel happier opening 2.28 than any later version. I'm glad that I know the past.

**Btw, why not learn the basics in both and then decide? 15 hours for A and 15 hours for B.** What's the worst that could happen? A broader perspective?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate NOW  I'd recommend 2.79. First, it's a good way to get familiar with the UI before it's changed and the way Blender works. Second, in 2.79 Eevee engine, which in 2.8. replaces BI, was introduced. It's the chance to learn the ropes and get used to before using "full" 2.8 Eevee version. And don't forget the Principled node that's a major development in materials and  phase one of "Node everything". Enjoy your Blender experience. Think of 2.79 as transitory. If you like it you're likely to use 2.8x

Comment: I am sticking to 2.9, until there is a stable release of 2.8, which is worth waiting for.

Answer (score 0):

I would disagree with Lukasz as the UI and keyboard commands are radically different in 2.8 from 2.79. The only disclaimer is that 2.8 could take a while to fully release. While the developers are work their heads off there is still a little work to be done. Moving from 2.79 to 2.8 is and will be a real pain for existing users, so I'd personally recommend starting when 2.8 comes out.
There are lots of tutorials on youtube, some good recommendations for getting started in it would be BlenderGuru and BornCG.
I wish you good luck in your future Blending!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure 2.8 will be good, probably better than our expectations. It is just a matter of time for long-time users to adjust to the new changes in 2.8. It will probably be a day or two for them to learn 2.8 and they will probably love it. 
Well, it is only the most nostalgic users who will wholly disagree with the new look of interface.

Comment: Have certain things in your memory for a decade of sometimes daily use and you'll find that a day or two won't cut it. Some changes took me months to adjust to and I still occasionally use the old way by accident. 10s of 1000s of repetitions can be persistent.

Comment: Maybe I´m crazy but after using both for a little while I think I like 2.79 interface more than 2.8 one.