# Start with Blender 2.79b or 2.8

Tags: versions

I’m new to Blender and need to learn Blender from scratch.

Should I start with version 2.79b or start using 2.8?

I’m expecting 2.8 to be mainstream before I reach any level of proficiency.

Comment: Hello! A question like this was asked before: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122408/learn-blender-2-7-now-or-wait-for-the-2-8-beta-release and it was considered off-topic for this site. In the other question I advised starting with the newest Beta, unless you are doing production work or working with one of the few features not yet updated.

Comment: Thank you, based on what I read, made the switch to 2.8!